# Proof of any interval being connected

Tags: real-analysis

Okay so according to the least upper bound property, let $A$ be a set on $\Bbb R$. $\sup(A)$ and $\inf(A)$ exist.

Let's assume that least upper bound property doesn't exist. 
Let $L$ be the set of lower bounds for $A$. there is $y_0$ in $L$ s.that $y_0>y_1$ for $y_1$ in $L$. there is also $y_0<y_2$ for $y_2$ in $L$. This could be built for all triples $(y_j,y_n,y_m)$ And this would imply that $L$ is an open set. My question is : How come it proves L is an open set. It proves that there could always be $y_j$ found for $y_o$ such that the neighbourhood around $y_o$ is always surrounded by infinitely many elements of L. But couldn't it be surrounded by infinitely many elements of both L and $L^C$? This would make $y_0$ the boundary of $L$ right? For it to be open any boundary shouldn't be contained. But how do we conclude that?

Generally, how do we conclude that $L$ is open from this point of view.

Comment: What you’ve written is pretty incoherent, I’m afraid. What is $B$ in the first sentence? And it’s not necessarily true that $\sup A$ exists, unless you allow $\infty$ as a value of the supremum. What is the *it* in the first sentence of the second paragraph? Judging by what follows, it’s $\inf A$. Are you assuming that $A$ is bounded below, assuming that $\inf A$ does not exist, and then asking why the set $L$ of lower bounds would be open?

Comment: Made changes, sorry about that